# How to refresh log4j after change of the external class logging level at runtime

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jena

I have some warnings which I want to disable. They comes from the

```
org.eclipse.lyo.oslc4j.provider.jena.JenaModelHelper
```

class. So I am using log4j and I call at rutime

```
Logger.getLogger("org.eclipse.lyo.oslc4j.provider.jena.JenaModelHelper").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

but nothing happens.

For that purpose I debug the problematic code and first 3 times the warn was displayed, but on the 4-th hit the level was changed.
I changed the log level at the begging(in the constructor) so I suppose there is some refresh mechanism in the log4j when the runtime applied rule is take into account.

Is there a way to trigger this to happen immediately?

Edit:
The warning message is:

```
WARNING: Property http://localhost:8080/dwa/rm/urn:rational::1-55422447386d3378-M-00000200/types/attrDef-7 could not be parsed as datatype http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime
com.hp.hpl.jena.datatypes.DatatypeFormatException: Lexical form '2015-06-10' is not a legal instance of Datatype[http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime -> class com.hp.hpl.jena.datatypes.xsd.XSDDateTime] Lexical form '2015-06-10' is not a legal instance of Datatype[http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime -> class com.hp.hpl.jena.datatypes.xsd.XSDDateTime] during parse -org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.InvalidDatatypeValueException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '2015-06-10' is not a valid value for 'dateTime'.
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.impl.LiteralLabelImpl.getValue(LiteralLabelImpl.java:339)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.Node_Literal.getLiteralValue(Node_Literal.java:39)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.LiteralImpl.getValue(LiteralImpl.java:98)
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You can disable the logging in you configuration file (log4j.properties), so this will be set at startup already:</strike>

<strike>log4j.logger.org.eclipse.lyo.oslc4j.provider.jena.JenaModelHelper=ERROR</strike>

The warning you posted looks much like a Java Util Logging message, those wont be controled by Log4J because its a different framework. You can either disable the message in your VMs "logging.properties" file:

```
org.eclipse.lyo.oslc4j.provider.jena.JenaModelHelper.level=SEVERE
```

Or you can add [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) to your project to redirect legacy framework messages to Log4J. To do this put [slf4j-api.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api), [jcl-over-slf4j.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j), [jul-to-slf4j.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j) and [slf4j-log4j12.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12) in your classpath.

Comment: In my project I have over 15 loggers and I do not want to reset the all configurations. 

Ps. I have log4j.xml with the configurations. If I put there the
<logger name="org.eclipse.lyo.oslc4j.provider.jena.JenaModelHelper">
         <level value="OFF" />
     </logger>

Nothing happens.

Comment: Can you post on of the warning messages.

Comment: I added in the main post.

Comment: OOO that's why all that I tried with log4j does not work.

Comment: I add logging.properties in src/main/resources package but the same error appears.

Comment: You need to change the file that you can find in yout JVM/lib directory.

Comment: OK, but it will work only on my machine I need my application to work on other environment. How to change it globally is there a Maven way or something like that?