# How to override logging.properties during application execution?

Tags: java, maven, logging, java.util.logging

I have an application which use a external library which dumps a big amount of warning messages which slows the application at runtime.

```
WARNING: Property http://localhost:8080/dwa/rm/urn:rational::1-55422447386d3378-M-00000200/types/attrDef-7 could not be parsed as datatype http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime
com.hp.hpl.jena.datatypes.DatatypeFormatException: Lexical form '2015-06-10' is not a legal instance of Datatype[http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime -> class com.hp.hpl.jena.datatypes.xsd.XSDDateTime] Lexical form '2015-06-10' is not a legal instance of Datatype[http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime -> class com.hp.hpl.jena.datatypes.xsd.XSDDateTime] during parse -org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.InvalidDatatypeValueException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '2015-06-10' is not a valid value for 'dateTime'.
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.impl.LiteralLabelImpl.getValue(LiteralLabelImpl.java:339)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.Node_Literal.getLiteralValue(Node_Literal.java:39)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.LiteralImpl.getValue(LiteralImpl.java:98)
```

This external library uses Java logging API. Deep problem info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477005/how-to-refresh-log4j-after-change-of-the-external-class-logging-level-at-runtime):

I tried with

```
Logger.getLogger("org.eclipse.lyo.oslc4j.provider.jena.JenaModelHelper").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

but once it is take into consideration, otherwise is not on different run. So I need to solve my problem in general way - to override  **logging.properties** file.

If the application works only on my machine I can do:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Temp\logging.properties
```

But it is a web application and it runs on different environment on which I do not have a control. So is it a way to disable messages from that problem class? Using maven to package the new configurations or some other trick?

Comment: What servlet container are you using to run the web application?

Answer (score 1):

I think that a possible solution is this below:

```
    System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", "C:\Temp\logging.properties ");
```

Comment: The problem is that my application takes that not at the begging of its execution.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the only way I could change the settings was through the JMX Logging Beans on the console

Answer (score 0):

> I tried with
>   `Logger.getLogger("org.eclipse.lyo.oslc4j.provider.jena.JenaModelHelper").setLevel(Level.OFF);`

[You have to prevent loggers from being garbage collected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923754/selenium-many-logs-how-to-remove) if you are changing any setting programmatically.