# Java Logger Makes New txt File Everytime

Tags: java, logging, random

#other code & randomizer

```
if(outcome == 1){
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");
    FileHandler fh;
    fh = new FileHandler("C:\\Temp\\Dice_roll\\Logs.txt", true);
    logger.addHandler(fh);
    logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
    fh.setFormatter(formatter);
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Outcome 1.");
}
```

This is supposed to add more text into the txt file, which it does. BUT, it also makes another txt file called Log.txt.**1** and then if I roll it again, Log.txt.**2** and so on. How would I fix this?

**Any help will be much appreciated.**

Comment: Are you restarting the program between runs?

Comment: @stdunbar no the whole program is in a while loop, there is a button to exit.

Comment: can you post your logger props file ?

Comment: Its just a txt file.

Comment: Move the code to setup the logger above the loop.  Every loop you are adding a new file handler.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a new `FileHandler` each time you try to log.
It has to be done only once!

You have to separate your `Logger` setup and its use.

Note that your logger has to be declared as `static final` otherwise it could be garbage collected and you could have to set it up again.

Setup code

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");
static {
    FileHandler fh;
    try {
        fh = new FileHandler("C:\\Temp\\Dice_roll\\Logs.txt", true);
        logger.addHandler(fh);
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
        fh.setFormatter(formatter);
    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
}
```

Logging

```
if(outcome == 1){
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Outcome 1.");
}
```

Note that if I were you, I would rather use a [configuration file](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/configuration.html).

Comment: The logger has to be declared static final otherwise the FileHandler will get [garbage collected and the logger setting are lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923754/selenium-many-logs-how-to-remove/40934452#40934452).

Comment: @C.Champagne the line `fh = new FileHandler("C:\\Temp\\Dice_roll\\Logs.txt", true);` is an error, the error is: `unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`.

Comment: @MasterHackerLOIS it just means that you need to catch a possible exception. See my updated code. Note that I still advise you to use configuration instead.

Comment: @MasterHackerLOIS By the way don't forget to create the directory where the log file is created if it doesn't exist yet ;)