# Best way for closing FileHandler on REST API's

Tags: java, file, logging, weblogic, filehandler

I don't know how to handle my FileHandler on API REST

I have a REST API installed at Weblogic, I'm using Java Logging and when my app starts, inits the logger, and open the FileHandler.
Like i never close the FileHandler the `.lck` file that is created stays at my logs folder. I really don't care the presence of that file, but when i redeploy the app, like the FileHandler is still open, my app starts a new log file (ex: `myLog.log.0`, `myLog.log.1`). I have read that JVM itself should be closing FileHandler but that is not happening. 
I have tried to `addShutodownHook` for closing FileHandler, but that code is not working, if I redeploy the app, it still stays open.

```java
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class GenericApplication extends Application {
    public GenericApplication() {
        initSwagger();
        initLog();

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                CtgLogger.fileJson.close();
                // fileJson is my FileHandler, i made it public static to call him here.
            }
        });
    }
```

My `initLog()` method just calls the next `CtgLogger.setup()`...

```java
public static void setup() throws IOException {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
    String level = PropertiesUtil.get("ctg.log.level");
    logger.setLevel(LEVEL_MAP.get(level));

    String filePath = PropertiesUtil.get("ctg.log.path");
    String fileSize = PropertiesUtil.get("ctg.log.max.size");
    String fileCount = PropertiesUtil.get("ctg.log.max.count");
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(fileSize) && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(fileSize) &&
        NumberUtils.isNumber(fileSize) && NumberUtils.isNumber(fileCount)) {
        fileJson = new FileHandler(filePath != null ? filePath : DEFAULT_LOG_NAME,
            Integer.parseInt(fileSize), Integer.parseInt(fileCount), true);
    } else {
        fileJson = new FileHandler(filePath != null ? filePath : DEFAULT_LOG_NAME);
    }
    jsonFormatter = new JsonCustomFormatter();
    fileJson.setFormatter(jsonFormatter);
    for (Handler h: logger.getHandlers())
        h.close();
    logger.addHandler(fileJson);
}
```

And that's all, then I just call my endpoints and use my logger.

My question is, should I open and close my FileHandler each time a endpoint is called? Or is there a better way for doing this?

Comment: Can't you use instance variables?

Comment: For what? My FileHandler is instanced at my logger constructor. Sorry don't understand your point. (My bad english)

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, should I open and close my FileHandler each time a endpoint is called? Or is there a better way for doing this?

No need to open and close every time the endpoint is called.

1. Remove the shutdown hook code.  The LogManager will close any **attached** file handler for you on shutdown.
2. Change `logger` to a static final reference so it is [impossible to garbage collect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923754/selenium-many-logs-how-to-remove). This ensures your settings are maintained.
3. Since you are using JavaEE use the [javax.annotation.PostConstruct](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) and [javax.annotation.PreDestroy](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html) annotations to manage your logger settings.
4. If you close a FileHandler manually, make sure you call [Logger::remove(Handler)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/Logger.html#removeHandler(java.util.logging.Handler)) so that handler can be garbage collected.  You current code only closes the handler.

```java
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
    private volatile FileHandler fileJson;

    public void preDestroy() {
       Handler h = this.fileJson;
       this.fileJson = null;
       if (h != null) {
           h.close();
       }
       logger.removeHandler(h);  
    }

    @PostConstruct 
    public void setup() throws IOException {
        if (fileJson != null) {
            preDestroy();
        }

        String level = PropertiesUtil.get("ctg.log.level");
        logger.setLevel(LEVEL_MAP.get(level));

        String filePath = PropertiesUtil.get("ctg.log.path");
        String fileSize = PropertiesUtil.get("ctg.log.max.size");
        String fileCount = PropertiesUtil.get("ctg.log.max.count");
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(fileSize) && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(fileSize) &&
        NumberUtils.isNumber(fileSize) && NumberUtils.isNumber(fileCount)) {
            fileJson = new FileHandler(filePath != null ? filePath : DEFAULT_LOG_NAME,
                Integer.parseInt(fileSize), Integer.parseInt(fileCount), true);
        } else {
               fileJson = new FileHandler(filePath != null ? filePath : DEFAULT_LOG_NAME);
        }
        jsonFormatter = new JsonCustomFormatter();
        fileJson.setFormatter(jsonFormatter);
        for (Handler h: logger.getHandlers()) {
            h.close();
            logger.removeHander(h);
        }
        logger.addHandler(fileJson);
    }
```