# Tomcat log with 'java.util.logging' stops working after spring migration

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, logging, migration

After migrating my application from spring 1.5.21 to spring 2.0.9 my logfile on actuator/logfile doesn't work properly when user in tomacat 9.

I am using lib "java.util.logging.Level".

A simple:

```
Logger.getLogger(Classname.class.getName())
                        .log(Level.SEVERE, "Teste: " + variable, ex);
```

doesn't appear on spring.log file.

This file was configured in a .properties file inside Spring boot project, like this:

```
logging.path=${user.home}/.path/logs/
```

But somethings are not stored in the file, by example "SPRING BANNER" or every Logger.getLogger command inside my code.

In spring 1.5.21 appeared everything on spring.log file.

I use the IDE Netbeans, and inside netBeans everything is logged properly.
But if I deploy the .war file of my application into Tomcat it doesn't appear on actuator/logfile (Stored on spring.log on path told above).

In my pom.xml I changed of:

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.21.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

to:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

Additional information:
I Saw that the log instruction appears normally on catalina.out file, but I would like it to work on actuator/logfile;

Can anyone help me with this issue ?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

> A simple: [snip] doesn't appear on spring.log file.

[Loggers are subject to garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923754/selenium-many-logs-how-to-remove).  Write your logging statements like:

```
private static final String CLASS_NAME = Classname.class.getName();
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CLASS_NAME);

...

if (logger.isLoggable(Level.SEVERE)) {
   logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Teste: " + variable, ex);
}
```

3rd party libs can remove the attached handlers from the loggers.  [Print the logger tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882648/logging-not-showing) so you can determine if it is an issue with handlers being removed or a level issue.

> I Saw that the log instruction appears normally on catalina.out file, but I would like it to work on actuator/logfile;

The console handler is usually installed on the root logger.  The root logger is not subject to garbage collection.